# How to climb up when hanging in the Female Ward chapter?

Tags: outlast

I am in the part where you have to hang down from some broken planks and move sideways, hand by hand. That itself wasn't explained in the game, I found out by accident that this is even possible.

Where I was:

I just walked through the dark room from which two club wearing cannibals come after you. The next room had completely destroyed floor, leaving only few planks to walk on. According to the walkthrough, it's the room where you lose your camera once you get through it.

What I did:

- First I thought I am supposed to walk on planks, leaning to the wall, as usual.
- When I tried that, I always fell. One time, instead of falling down I ended hanging from those planks.
- I found out that I can move in both directions while hanging down.
- I moved to desired location but couldn't get myself up

Now as I hang down, how to climb up on the platform to my left?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: Or maybe describe the last thing you did in this level?

Comment: so in layman terms you want to ask which button to pull yourself up ?

Comment: @NamikazeSheena Exactly. I tried jump button [space] and up arrow. But I eventually found out that you ARE supposed to walk on that ledge, it's just little bit harder to get on it properly.  Not sure if I should self-answer or delete the question.

Comment: Just post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying ten more times, I figured out that you're not supposed to hang from the planks at all. At this particular spot in the game, you just have to pay special attention when walking by leaning to the wall. When starting to lean, first turn so that your left hand faces the wall, then slowly lean your back to wall and start walking.